# Hide unused rows on chart when filtering Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have made a Gantt chart in excel that is attached to a pivot table. It has about 100 lines and when I filter the pivot table the Gant chart that depends on the pivot table has the same amount of rows. I would like to know how I can hide these rows that are hanging down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used conditional formatting to hide the cells.